# Perl variable initialization bug using in a subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

So I have a situation where I have a function with two named arguments, but if both are used the function needs to die.  I'm not sure if this is a bug, or if there's something intrinsic I'm not understanding about Perl variables.

Here's the simplified code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

foreach my $number (1..5)
{
    fooBar(foo => $number);
}

sub fooBar 
{
    my %args = (
        foo => undef,
        bar => undef,
        @_
    );

    my $foo = $args{foo} if defined $args{foo};
    my @bar = @{$args{bar}} if defined $args{bar};
    print Dumper(\@bar);

    if (defined $foo)
    {
        die('fooBar() received both a foo and a bar and didn\'t know which to use!') if @bar;
        push(@bar, $foo);
    }

    print Dumper(\@bar);
    return (\@bar);
}

# > $VAR1 = [];
# > $VAR1 = [
# >           1
# >         ];
# > $VAR1 = [
# >           1
# >         ];
# > fooBar() received both a foo and a bar and didn't know which to use! at ./example.pl line 27.
```

Here's my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

foreach my $number (1..5)
{
    fooBar(foo => $number);
}

sub fooBar 
{
    my %args = (
        foo => undef,
        bar => undef,
        @_
    );

    my $foo;
    my @bar;
    $foo = $args{foo} if defined $args{foo};
    @bar = @{$args{bar}} if defined $args{bar};
    print Dumper(\@bar);

    if (defined $foo)
    {
        die('fooBar() received both a foo and a bar and didn\'t know which to use!') if @bar;
        push(@bar, $foo);
    }

    print Dumper(\@bar);
    return (\@bar);
}

# > $VAR1 = [];
# > $VAR1 = [
# >           1
# >         ];
# > $VAR1 = [];
# > $VAR1 = [
# >           2
# >         ];
# > $VAR1 = [];
# > $VAR1 = [
# >           3
# >         ];
# > $VAR1 = [];
# > $VAR1 = [
# >           4
# >         ];
# > $VAR1 = [];
# > $VAR1 = [
# >           5
# >         ];
```

My question is, why does this fix the problem?  In the first example, the first time `fooBar()` is called, `@bar` is getting initialized despite failing the if condition.  The second time through the loop, `@bar` has somehow retained its information from the first loop, yet it doesn't complain about being reinitialized.  It seems to me that either a) `@bar` should be wiped after the subroutine finishes (which is what I was expecting), b) `@bar` shouldn't be initialized after it fails the `if defined` test, or c) `@bar` should complain that it's being reinitialized the second time through the loop.  I'm pretty confused here, is this just a bug?

Comment: ah, you try to find bug in Perl? do you really understand what Perl understand in your code?;) I think that assignment inside lazy if-clause (do{my $var = value;}if value); should cause a problem

Comment: just don't do `my ... if`.  but what actually happens (currently; it is flagged in the doc as subject to change) is that `my` has both a compile-time an a run time effect; the if can skip the run time effect, keeping perl from knowing it needs to reinitializing the variable at end of scope.

Comment: in such cases, try `perlcritic` too: it says: _Variable declared in conditional statement at line 22, column 5.  Declare variables outside of the condition.  (Severity: 5)_ (and the same for the line 23)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This only conditionally creates a new variable, and can lead to strange to understand results:

```
my $foo = $args{foo} if defined $args{foo};
```

[perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) has this to say:

> NOTE: The behaviour of a my, state, or our modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, my $x if ... ) is undefined. The value of the my variable may be undef, any previously assigned value, or possibly anything else. Don't rely on it. Future versions of perl might do something different from the version of perl you try it out on. Here be dragons.

Don't try to define a `$foo` variable; just use `$args{foo}`.  Or just do the assignment unconditionally; there's nothing wrong with assigning undef.

Comment: Very interesting.  I had other reasons for formatting the code this way that aren't apparent in my example, although looking over it I'm... not sure what those reasons were anymore.  Perhaps I'll get rid of it and see what breaks.  Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @JasonHamje, documentation ... you know what you should do ;)

Comment: @ysth I think he was making the point to Jason about why its good to document your own code. Since Jason said he had other reasons for formatting his code but cannot remember them. If he had documented them then he wouldnt have to remember.

Comment: @gaussblurinc; fair enough, fair enough :P

Comment: @ysth, uh, english sarcasm so simple.. uh, no, I mean that OP should read it in future